# d3 stacked bar chart values not showing up on chart

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js

So I have created a D3 Stacked Bar Chart, but I can't seem to figure out how to make the values of the bars show up on the chart.  I can display Text "Sample" to each bar, but I can't figure out how to retrieve the data.  I tried using this... .text(function(d) {return d.total; }) but with no luck.

jfiddle here.... http://jsfiddle.net/rasweat/D3ErQ/1/

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            var margin = {top: 60, right: 20, bottom: 100, left: 100},
                                width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
                                height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                            var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
                                .rangeRoundBands([0, width-100], .1); //width-100 to make room for the legend.

                            var y = d3.scale.linear()
                                .rangeRound([height, 0]);

                            var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                                //.range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);
                                .range(["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e","d62728"]); //blue, orange, red
                                //color code for Progress Report
                                //.range(["#00FFFF","#00FF00","#990099","#FF0000","#FFFF00"]);

                            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                                .scale(x)
                                .orient("bottom");

                            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                                .scale(y)
                                .orient("left")
                                .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

                            var svg = d3.select("#area_progress_report").append("svg")
                                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                              .append("g")
                                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

                                // Get the data
                            //var data = [{"Commodity":"Base","num_complete_print":"3","num_incomplete_print":15},{"Commodity":"Blade","num_complete_print":"1","num_incomplete_print":53},{"Commodity":"DTE","num_complete_print":"1","num_incomplete_print":17},{"Commodity":"HUB","num_complete_print":"0","num_incomplete_print":"18"},{"Commodity":"MH","num_complete_print":"0","num_incomplete_print":"18"},{"Commodity":"Mid","num_complete_print":"0","num_incomplete_print":18},{"Commodity":"Top","num_complete_print":"0","num_incomplete_print":18}];
                            var data = <?php echo json_encode($dataset_progress001); ?>;                                
                            //alert(data);
                            //d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
                              color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Commodity"; }));

                              data.forEach(function(d) {
                                var y0 = 0;
                                d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
                                d.total = d.ages[d.ages.length - 1].y1;
                              });

                              //use this to sort the bars from largest to smallest
                              //data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.total - a.total; });

                              x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Commodity; }));
                              y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);

                              svg.append("g")
                                  .attr("class", "x axis")
                                  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                                  .call(xAxis)
                                  .selectAll("text")  //added this line through rotate to change orientation of x axis
                                    .style("text-anchor", "end")
                                    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                                    .attr("dy", "-1em")
                                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                                        return "rotate(-90)" 
                                        });

                              svg.append("g")
                                  .attr("class", "y axis")
                                  .call(yAxis)
                                .append("text")
                                  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                                  .attr("y", 6)
                                  .attr("dy", ".71em")
                                  .style("text-anchor", "end");
                                //  .text("Population");

                                //grid lines  y.ticks controls the number of lines
                                svg.selectAll("line.horizontalGrid").data(y.ticks(10)).enter()
                                    .append("line")
                                        .attr(
                                        {
                                            "class":"horizontalGrid",
                                            "x1" : 0,
                                            "x2" : width-60,
                                            "y1" : function(d){ return y(d);},
                                            "y2" : function(d){ return y(d);},
                                            "fill" : "none",
                                            "shape-rendering" : "crispEdges",
                                            "stroke" : "grey",
                                            "stroke-width" : "1px"
                                        });

                              var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
                                  .data(data)
                                .enter().append("g")
                                  .attr("class", "g")
                                  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.Commodity) + ",0)"; });

                              state.selectAll("rect")
                                  .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
                                .enter().append("rect")
                                  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                                  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
                                  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
                                  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

                              var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
                                  .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
                                .enter().append("g")
                                  .attr("class", "legend")
                                  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

                              legend.append("rect")
                                  .attr("x", width - 18)
                                  .attr("width", 18)
                                  .attr("height", 18)
                                  .style("fill", color);

                              legend.append("text")
                                  .attr("x", width - 24)
                                  .attr("y", 9)
                                  .attr("dy", ".35em")
                                  .style("text-anchor", "end")
                                  .text(function(d) { return d; });

                            //Added y label 10/28
                            svg.append("text")
                                .attr("class", "y label")
                                .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                                .attr("y", -60)
                                .attr("x",-70)
                                .attr("dy", ".75em")
                                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                                .text("Number Of Components");

                            //Add Title
                            svg.append("text")
                                .attr("x", (width/2) )//(width / 2))             
                                .attr("y", -20) //0 - (margin.top / 2))
                                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
                                .style("font-size", "20px") 
                                .style("text-decoration", "underline")  
                                .text("Inspection Progress Report");

                            state.selectAll("text")
                              .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
                              .enter()
                              .append("text")
                              .attr("x", x.rangeBand()/2)
                              .attr("y", function(d, i) { return y(d.y1) + (y(d.y0) - y(d.y1))/2; })
                              .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                              //.text(function(d) {return d.total; })
                              .text("sample")
                        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change this line

```
.data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
```

to actually give `data()` your data. If you have an array with all the ages named `ages`, then it would be:

```
.data(ages)
```

The `d` argument in `function(d)` references nothing since `data()` is actually the method where you input your data.

Comment: I have tried as you said, but I can't get it to work.  Can you update the jfiddle ...  http://jsfiddle.net/rasweat/D3ErQ/1/ and show me?  Please

Comment: The problem is that when you do `.data(function(d) { return d.ages; })` you actually restrain the range of your data to the elements inside the `ages` array, so when you try to access `d.total` it is undefined (because `d` represents one of your `ages` array. I'll try to find a workaround on your jsfiddle.

Comment: This works the way you want I guess: http://jsfiddle.net/D3ErQ/4/
But it is ugly because I use the `d.y1` attribute to get the value of the bar. There is no reason that the bar has to be as tall as the value it represents, it could be twice as tall for example. You probably should put inside the `ages` array an attribute for each object with the value that the bar actually represents.

Comment: I thank you so much.  I tried that, but like you said it is posting the value of the bar height not each individual segment of the bar's value.  I am still learning D3 so if there is a way to add the data element inside the ages array I'm not sure how to do it.  will continue to look.

Comment: Also I was confused with the attributes `d.y0` and `d.y1`, I thought they were representing coordinate values but they are in fact your data values that you then transform to coordinate values with your `y` scale. Then you do not need to change your `data` array but simply have to do what I did in the fifth iteration of the fiddle

Comment: Perfect!  I made a minor modification so it won't show values that are 0 ... function(d, i) { if((d.y1 - d.y0)<1){return '';}else{return d.y1 - d.y0;} }  THANK YOU SO MUCH!